# adding more items to NavigationView takes to long

Tags: c#, uwp, navigationview

I want to add 1500 items to the NavigationView
I used actionblock but it is still very slow and it takes about 10 seconds for items to be added in ui

```
private ObservableCollection<NavigationViewItem> data;
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
private void DoSomethingWithCustomer(NavigationViewItem c)
        {

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                data.Add(c);
            }).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                NavigationView.MenuItemsSource = data;
            }, taskScheduler);
        }
```

and:

```
ActionBlock<NavigationViewItem> action = new ActionBlock<NavigationViewItem>(DoSomethingWithCustomer, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
            });
            var coll = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories("D:\\Pic\\Art");
            foreach (var customer in coll)
            {
                var item = new NavigationViewItem { Content = new DirectoryInfo(customer).Name };

                action.Post(item);
            }
            action.Complete();
            await action.Completion;
```

I tried and the EnumerateDirectories is done in less than 1 second But it takes a long time to add items to the ui

Comment: I've had similar problems before and it was because the UI was trying to render the items even though they were not in view. If I recall, my solution was to set a flag to not try and render the items that were not actually in the screen.
Or i had to use a different control. Can't remember exactly, but the issue was that the UI was actually trying to draw all the items being added and it seems like that is your issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is slow because `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface which has an event called `CollectionChanged`. This event fires everytime an item is added to the collection and the UI (NavigationView) is listening to it.

This means that every time an item is added, the UI has to render it making the process of adding hundreds or thousands of items slow.

Your best bet is to implement your own version of the `ObservableCollection` which delays firing that event until all items are added. An example of that can be found here: https://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/

```
public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
  private bool _suppressNotification = false;
 
  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!_suppressNotification)
      base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
  }
 
  public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
  {
    if (list == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
 
    _suppressNotification = true;
 
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
      Add(item);
    }
    _suppressNotification = false;
    OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
  }
}
```